# How do you load a bitmap file into a BitmapData object?

Tags: flash, actionscript, bitmap, drawing, bitmapdata

In Flash, the [BitmapData](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/8/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00001944.html) object can be used to store bitmaps in RAM, you can later draw them to a MovieClip using the [beginBitmapFill()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00001895.html) method.

How do you load an external bitmap file (.jpg) into a BitmapData object?

Even AS3 code would be helpful.

Comment: I don't really understand why you took your own answer instead of Cotton's.

Comment: Because I wanted an AS2 solution. Cotton's is AS3.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

AS3 code to load a PNG and "get" its bitmapData

```
var bitmapData:BitmapData;

var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
    loader.load(new URLRequest("../lib/img.png"));

function onComplete (event:Event):void
{
    bitmapData = Bitmap(LoaderInfo(event.target).content).bitmapData;
}
```

Comment: Just a note. You can't use a URLLoader for this

Comment: Another note. Loader adds some info to the bitmap, so trying to change some attributes like `name` directly from `event.target.content` . But as the OP creating a new bitmap is good.

Answer (score 9):

Refering to the first post by cotton.

Actually each image is a bitmap so all you need to do is

```
bitmapData = event.target.content.bitmapData
```

instead of

```
bitmapData = Bitmap(LoaderInfo(event.target).content).bitmapData;
```

Comment: No, `LoaderInfo.content` is a DisplayObject. All Bitmaps are DisplayObjects, but not all DisplayObjects are Bitmaps, hence the cast. By removing the casts, you are working around the type safety feature of the ActionScript language.

Answer (score 6):

taking from cotton and will, this will display the bitmap after it is loaded:

```
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.display.BitmapData;

var bitmapData:BitmapData;
var bmVis:Bitmap;

var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
    loader.load(new URLRequest("put url here"));

function onComplete (event:Event):void
{
    trace("loaded!");
    bitmapData = event.target.content.bitmapData;
    bmVis = new Bitmap(bitmapData);
    this.addChild(bmVis);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to load the external file (.jpg) into a MovieClip and wait for it to load.

Then take a snapshot of the MovieClip that contains the external file, into your BitmapData object.

```
myBitmap = new BitmapData(myMC._width, myMC._height,true,0x00FFFFFF)

myBitmap.draw( myMC)
```

---

See [Introducing the Image API in Flash 8.](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/image_api_05.html)

Answer (score 1):

GUI phase:
Load the image into the library (file -> import -> library).
In the library browser, right-click and hit "properties", notice that it is X by Y pixels.
Open up the "advanced" tab.
Select "export for Action Script". Export as myImg

Actionscript phase:

```
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.display.Bitmap; //needed?
..........
var myPic:BitmapData = new myImg(X,Y);
```