# Dynamically loading images given filename

Tags: actionscript-3

I have the following code which traverses an XMLList of nodes:

```
function determineFacilities(facilities:XMLList, item:MovieClip) {
    for(var i:int = 0; i > facilities.length(); i++) {
        if(Boolean(facilities[i].text()) == true) {
            var imgName:String = facilities[i].nodeName + ".png";
            // need to load and position image here
        }
    }
}
```

If the current node's text is true, then I need to load an Image with the same name as the node (plus the extension) and position it.

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var bitmap:Bitmap;

var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
    loader.load(new URLRequest(imgName));

function onComplete (event:Event):void
{
    bitmap = Bitmap(LoaderInfo(event.target).content)
    bitmap.x = yourX;
    bitmap.y = yourY;
    addChild(bitmap)
}
```

extracted from: [How do you load a bitmap file into a BitmapData object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702164/how-do-you-load-a-bitmap-file-into-a-bitmapdata-object)